# magento search results display in invert order

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've got problem with magento quick search. When i'm typing some query the results are sorted DESCently, from the worst to the best, the most accurate result is the last one, and the worst one is first, when i'm using advanced search everything seems to be okay. How can i change the sort order?

Comment: Check out the following qusetion and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953715/magento-search-not-returning-expected-results

Answer (score 0):

If you mean ajax popup window, that is shown when you typing search query, then there is no sort asc or desc. Results are sorted by search time (last search will be shown first).

See app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Autocomplete.php function getSuggestData(). You can override this function to yours logic.

If you mean searc result, then you need to look at function setListOrders() in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php